# How do I list the names and addresses for those employees whose addresses has at least 3 digits?

Tags: sql, regex, string, digits

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee;

CREATE TABLE employee (

  Fname varchar(15) NOT NULL,

  Minit char(1) default NULL,

  Lname varchar(20) NOT NULL,

  Ssn varchar(11) NOT NULL,

  Bdate date default NULL,

  Address varchar(50) default NULL,

  Sex char(1) default NULL,

  Salary float(10,2) default NULL,

  Super_ssn char(9) default NULL,

  Dno int(11) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (Ssn)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I'm guessing

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Address 
FROM employee 
WHERE Address  WHERE Address REGEXP '^[0-9]{3}[ ]';
```

Except this only returns addresses with exactly 3 digits

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Change `{3}` for `{3,}`.  That will make it an unspecified range of three or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{m,}`. This matches at least m occurrences of the preceding subexpression

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Address 
FROM employee 
WHERE Address  WHERE Address REGEXP '^[0-9]{3,}[ ]';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of length function

```
SELECT FNAME, LNAME, ADDRESS
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE LENGTH(ADDRESS) >= 3;
```

Comment: What about the _three or more **digits**_ ?